# how to open or create .out file with permissions in C

Tags: c, file-io

I have problem I want to open a file with `.out` extension or if it not exist then it should create it with permissions to read and write and by opening file I want to erase his content

```
variable = open( "file.out", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRWXO, O_TRUNC )
```

I used this command but it always fails I think I have bad flags as far I know:

> O_RDWR is to open file with write and read permission
>
> O_CREAT it creates file if not exist
>
> S_IRWXO is used by O_CREAT to make the file readable and writable
>
> O_TRUNC erase all data from file

Comment: When the call to `open()` fails, you can look at the value of `errno` to determine the cause of the error.

Comment: Did you check `errno`?

Comment: Whether write permission can't kept using open function to other is the failure for you?

Comment: no i didnt but i will

Comment: ohh i didnt mentioned my program stuck at this command i need to edit my post so it can be more accurate

Answer (score 2):

`open` doesn't take 4 arguments - only 2 or 3. All of the `O_` flags should be OR'ed together in the second argument. Also, `S_IRWXO` will give permissions *only* to others, not to the owner or group owner. You meant `S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO` probably. But I'd rather just see an octal number; the macros aren't more readable.

```
variable = open( "file.out", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0777 )
```

Comment: your command helped a little bit now my program doesnt stuck at this line but it returns negative value so it failed anyway

Comment: i dont know much about perror what should i use as argument?

Answer (score 0):

If you want read/write/execute permission for the current user/owner use: `S_IRWXU`:

```
S_IRWXO

Read, write, and search or execute permission for users other than the 
file owner. S_IRWXO is the bitwise inclusive-OR of S_IROTH, S_IWOTH, 
and S_IXOTH.

S_IRWXU

Read, write, and search, or execute, for the file owner; S_IRWXG is the
bitwise inclusive-OR of S_IRUSR, S_IWUSR, and S_IXUSR.
```

Doing `open( "file.out", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU, O_TRUNC );` and `ls -l` gives:

```
-rwx------. 1 perreal perreal 0 Apr 29 15:52 file.out
```